# TypeScript Template literals Array Join

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation

I found a definition for a type level [`Split` function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201028&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#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-bCgACyiBaRQAvpoB0OAaPpNPZ4PSMPQL0UIyp93QAB+euN-ugQST7AALjHE6KjmgS4vY-vjmuyEZl83r6ZU9Al+PiiCD4PAAwmQpDMLw1xSqYWYAlWPxTlqYAADLSGgyoSIYzCiIw3j5JiGCYLGTjOioWHetm6DMMwgqMK6VpoIE7QMG2HCYggGjnrsrFYpA56fEErwsIJ+xiJAfIKEohBgNx7HnoIsDqPQglkvgrwwlghjCVihzidYBCIaAKGkGgapOIQiDMp2WAYGUNgmo44BkpMCTCLwmZ4Bg9CHCSMa8PRfwAi+twnluxj4LsiAyIg0iSE2hatvUkGYpAOBDLsRloAAzGZgJoNgGiiLwTq5ZZ9DWbZ8COBgzpcNQOTGOQgTMJmnloE0mw8Ls6lWiVIJgjMASIOkfifKwZX5MO9pXGk5V3M47VtDwSL9DV1pVrs9DMBooBgbwJSMo49HkPlyCuOQ-lJt1TIxP+aL4DG6hpboSbgJMcopmmiA8PmhY5q9krSqQ1YGYSFJhqQ3q8DGnbZE2kqgMqAAMiMAKSOFQJC+E4vAUjdGI8Zxz1kqAABCiD0D9igk9QyBrAA0glcjyqmFrIJT2A5g8SqI5oqKuJoCqCwqDzA8M+KgAAEswcKFo4LPpjBI7qX6oB4QRjrkFWhD0hgjKxGUkOq1gJWsiUSKg2cQ2QF1BHKGU8AqCFn50g1lIzKAMY+Wgpuug8AAamgAJqaAAWg8jg63r-nGZw8jGfr227YTSbs8m2AAe98tfWziuc3zI4fKQvAh4orCF7wyIYNmIsGeMoAAErtK4GQUYzUwvIsMgg9ajEtVhhAybDyt26QDt0kU-IuwioCkdQHuIBRePZ26bYsE7B27KyJ5FGgpDUGQRB+CQdCELPdJkLwYbYJPV0lY56jOeYsC8NzquGqd+WXoPvHueY5O64Jag7EExiwMMsCQLw3Ylk6GvfKrxaCICyHqZgtpjJFwcBAIB2RzL5RqDIKijAYSIEdmvQUkBYC7AtJPYq-l8ogngF8JEEtFA+nMhAwMJpCaJmJnMKweZ2zlkrDMRwAARARnYhEllrLKQ8DYqziK7G9PcK9ZAAG0AC6P5ZFTAUYQb0UZlEaK0boRsOiywSJ7HONcAJwBTgHCIuxq51wAFUdz7lAKo8AjgcSaF4VgHMzjRHVk0ZeVRkx1EAG4DIZQRrEdoSA6FMDDFcWMmIMFwl9MoLGGRZCw0ZKkngigKhogoPlFqpJPRgDevlRidB0G9XdmvAMWBIidlAGIik-k4iYDvKQFARRzZEnCuLTA8cEQgkSfRR2sY0AUHAkyLWT0DAxNMoydo-JITOnkbjeQel0aOzWUQfkbZqp4IRCcf0MxdjnG8OYuIjBKgoJKtIEQvAqzLS2cwRwJ0zpQLbLGXAKgkS6muWQQ2V8b4aR2mUXSFyVEyCWWAZMmgEWAgpMfXi3CxSTHQvKPxyAcxVkcA8TQNdQHIVQqAbKhyNnEQadAik+xSRVU+aAH5bg+DkCZSQrB1sibYtMnil4nNw6PFJaLdKlKFTzzYRkO8CTozrN+FhEcWdvqKw+fSts+0wq7G7Ko3o+V8gYHYPccA6jVEiMgD06Q-TsAWsmNQCaJr7jOPUbuI67Y4wlUYsa01AAKcAABKGBrB6KbwwFKCCqToApQBMVCyp12KHVdnA7A1ByD4o1r1J1frQD+ucSGte4zXB8oMFaV00Ad4unIHadeTIbneywp2SpuwVpavqJtRO4FOhEHgNQOIJVukYF6XalN092VdBcOxR0zp0K7GyLIHqkcG1lGQNFO4-l5HXGGowea5kujYBkNQWNRd82TCDYiqYI6Z0YqxWgSY2UhV8IeKqDUxLxUGW1LbNlTcoIa0Pr8GQKU+Aq38pGSsHcGD3qmNK59-jX3qk0JlUVJKyW7G-T1K0FJ+RgRhNkegwHHBn3ulheAOE2pIN+PlcmnLGAZriFGqIABHagCg+Cb0gDCWdJUiAoOgBmrAjtv6EBoSJI0NJTiOC3t-QmIBdivFAKsdEtTCBBBpmgc0cYSmOxETELk-BFD8kxLsQwyBkCwHwOeEAsIFiKE0Hx6AwAvKkEzPQfkwBJAoFoMAZUmVEbKgAOyI2C2qAAbAAVhC8qAAnAADgVGFhUIwFNKbica0gs1VZok2kQE99pNCscUCoDM2QeA6cfIKBuKgyCmfM5Z6zwBbPmfs454Ad5BTYBq52SAmZPPrtOvgXz-mEuBbVGqQLMWAvIzVBFhUgXAspfFr0SAwRYYxkXgQM07AQgjvtH4W+rH2OOfmCQVAjBt2xjoFKUAuxaCr3E+IeRkmCARwZNdXB+QM2gEUxQGm0LeD5Uc6e+52XsC7CavQagPAbLkD43ECgVsQHyfFmZizVmQAyA0qCBzKDgAyEwqITAihgCIDhPgFBYlUDaVQLCpQyk7C7F2GsEcNHGD+VAs2w+p7eBZGYHIVIkg5NgDRw1kAcRMx85kFoO8wYKf5GQLjpzJp8AuWfqT0gYEM1EAsAz+IT83gKleMqV40JEDAFGNTg4tOXt6-wEAA):

```js
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? string[] :
    S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] : [S];
```

Is there also a way to create a type level `Join<string[], string>` function, so I can use them for example for changing underscores to hyphens?

For example:

```js
type ChangeHyphensToUnderscore<T> = { [P in keyof T & string as `${Join(Split<P, '-'>, '_')}`]: T[P] };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is:

```
type Stringable = string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined;

type Join<A, Sep extends string = ""> = A extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] ? Rest extends [] ? `${First & Stringable}` : `${First & Stringable}${Sep}${Join<Rest, Sep>}` : "";
```

You can also improve performance slightly by utilizing [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization):

```
type Join<A, Sep extends string = "", R extends string = ""> = A extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] ? Join<Rest, Sep, R extends "" ? `${First & Stringable}` : `${R}${Sep}${First & Stringable}`> : R;
```

[Here's a playground for you to play.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwIYCMA20C8UAzgiqlAD5TICuAtphPBVJoqisM5gPbe7rJmNbNmbVkAEwgAzFBAkBuAFBLQkKACluKADwBBADSwIYKBAAewCJMJESaKAQBETgHyOoes5esTbAbRRpRigAMUR4YiMAOligkIAlCGIAXSgAfigk4m8rGyh-NMyAAwASAG9wyM4AMlh7DBwIAF9iqAAuKDLKiJy6uCQ0LFxmipgTUfKtXWzgI3GwV1aOqBdlVXBoABUARg9p5B1-HaMAJiMAZhSjJwBaN2UAekeoV4A9dKA)

Comment: This works when the elements of the array are statically known, but when providing like `Join<('a'|'b')[],','>` it assumes it returns always an empty string `""`. Any idea to make it work dynamically ? :D

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon What would the expected result even be?

Comment: yeah that would be an infinite set then `'' | 'a' | 'b' | 'a,a' | 'a,b' | 'b,a' | 'b,b' | 'a,a,a' | 'a,a,b' ...`, not sure if these can be represented in Typescript.